# Cannot catch value in Java Unit Test

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have the following service method:

```
public CommandDTO update(UUID uuid, EmployeeRequest request) {
    final List<Product> productList = productRepository
            .findAllByUuidOrderByOrderNumber(uuid); 

    final List<UUID> uuidList = request.getUuidList();

    for (int i = 0; i < uuidList.size(); i++) {        
        Product product = productList.get(i);
        product.setOrderNumber(i + 1);

        // how can I get the product value in this line? 
    }

    return CommandDTO.builder().uuid(uuid).build();
}
```

Normally, I use `ArgumentCaptor` in order to get values passing to repository or service. Howevcer, in this example, the product value that I want to get after `product.setOrderNumber(i + 1);` is not passing service or repository. For this reason I cannot get it. I am not sure if it would be possible using `@Spy` or `doAnswer`, but as far as I know, these methods cannot be used as the value is not passing to service or repo. Any idea?

Comment: You say that the product is not passing a service or repository. However, as I see it, the product comes from `productList` which is the return value of your `productRepository.findAllByUuidOrderByorderNumber()` method. So it does pass your repository. Can you clarify what you mean, for example by adding the relevant part of the test code you wrote?

Comment: I think you missed this part: *"... the product value that I want to get after `product.setOrderNumber(i + 1);` is not passing service or repository."*

Comment: I simply want to catch the product value after setting its order, after `product.setOrderNumber(i + 1);` line I mean.

Comment: Ok, maybe it doesn't pass the repository again, but considering that it originates from your repository (the `findBy....()` method), you can mock the return value of that method to return a list of products you choose, and then you already have access to those products within your test.

Comment: Could you give an example pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mock you repository to return list of mock's:

```
public test() {

    Product product1 = mock(Product.class);
    Product product2 = mock(Product.class);
    List list = Arraylist();
    list.add(product1);
    list.add(product2);

    when(productRepositoryMock.findAllByUuidOrderByOrderNumber(uuid))
       .thenReturn(list)
    when(product1).setOrderNumber(captor.capture)
```

In this case you can use ArgumentCaptor here, but I belive it's redundant in this case, and simple verify call will be enough

```
service.update(.....);

verify.(product1).setOrderNumber(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `product` variable comes from `productList`, which in turn comes from the `repository.findAllByUuidOrderByOrderNumber()` method. So if you mocked your repository, you could write something like this:

```java
Product givenProduct = new Product();
UUID givenUUID = UUID.randomUUID();
// Create an EmployeeRequest with a `uuidList`
EmployeeRequest givenRequest = new EmployeeRequest(/* TODO */); 
// Use Mockito to return a `productList` you choose
// This uses a static import of `Mockito.when()`
when(productRepository.findAllByUuidOrderByOrderNumber(givenUUID)).thenReturn(List.of(givenProduct));
service.updateRequest(givenUUID, givenRequest);
```

Theoretically you could even return a mocked product in the test logic above, but I suggest using a real `Product` object.

And now whatever happens to that product, can be asserted within your test.

For example:

```java
// `givenProduct` is element 0, and thus will get an orderNumber of 1
assertThat(givenProduct.getOrderNumber()).isEqualTo(1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but what is `product`? If I use the value that I used for mocking, then it would be meaningless to check if the order is updated or not. Any idea?

Comment: I was thinking of using ArgumentCaptor, etc. But not sure if the approach you suggested would be better.

Comment: @stack o right, that should be `givenProduct` as you can see in the first code snippet (which is the first part of the test). I updated the answer.

Comment: You could mock `Product` as well (then do so in the line where I construct `givenProduct`). However, for simple objects with some getters/setters I prefer using an actual `Product` object and just call the getter to see if the value matches. That improves readability.